# How to check that all data is supplied in a csv given by user?

Tags: database, dataframe, csv, unit-testing, user-input

I want to check if an employees csv that I'm getting from the user has all the data I need, just like this one:

```
emplyee_id, full_name, phone, age
303555303,Rachel Green,8620987654,30
404666404,Monica Geller,8644444500,28
404555403,Chandler Bing,8620987653,31
```

If the csv is missing data, I want to update the user. What's the most effective way to check it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is perhaps already been asked in some other form here in SO, but anyways here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.read_csv('yourtest.csv') #importing the file into a pandas dataframe
x=test.isnull().any(axis=1)
print(x[x==True].index.to_numpy()) #gives you the row numbers(as a numpy array) that has some of its values missing
```

isnull() checks each value of the dataframe(df) and sets True/False for each value. any() with axis=1(row-wise) outputs True if any element in the row is True.

So x is a series where index is the row number and its value(True/False) denotes whether that row has any null values or not. x[x==True] is just the way to select  rows that are True, and .index provides the row number.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It helped me to understand the whole proccess in this code.